# Centralizar paginação no Bootstrap v2.1.0

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Preciso centralizar uma paginação de resultados utilizando o Bootstrap v2.1.0, já tentei colocar o text-align na div mas também não deu. Esse é o código que estou usando:

```php
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="div_paginacao" class="span12">
        <ul class='pagination pagination-centered'><li><!-- páginas --></li></ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Já tentei também colocar outros spans acima e abaixo da div "div_paginacao" mas também não deu. Na verdade até deu, mas ao redimensionar a página, o espaçamento não diminui.

Answer (score 2):

A partir da versão 2.3.0, já é possível utilizar a classe `text-center`.

Caso não dê certo, utilize o `text-align` do css como no [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/xKSUH/)

Comment: Já tentei com o text-align mas também não deu certo

Comment: o proprio text-center do bootstrap não funcionou ? poste seu código com o css no jsfiddle para analisarmos

Comment: Então amigo, eu coloquei a versão errada, na verdade estou usando a 2.1.0, portanto, não tenho como colocar a classe text-center

Comment: Tinha colocado como resolvido, mas percebi que deu erro quando a paginação chega em um determinado numero, devido ao tamanho da div. Tem como alinhar uma div com o min-widht?

Comment: min-width é pra quando você deseja uma largura mínima fixa, dependendo pode até ajudar no alinhamento, mas não é pra isso que serve

Answer (score 2):

Problema resolvido.
A div ficou assim:

```html
<div id="div_paginacao" class="span12" style="width: 400px; margin: 0 auto; float: none;"></div>
```

Comment: Pelo que entendi, você não está querendo centralizar textos e sim divs, correto ? Nesse caso não seria melhor utilizar o .container acompanhado de .span-**-offset ?

Comment: Vou tentar usar sua alternativa amigo, até porque não deu certo com eu coloquei acima

Comment: Então amigo, até centraliza a div utilizando do container, span e offset, mas o problema é que se eu redimensiono a janela, a div não acompanha entende?

Comment: posta sua pagina inteira no jsfiddle com o css, provavelmente sua estrutura de pagina esta errada e esta conflitando.

Comment: Então amigo, o problema é que mesmo que eu poste a página toda, não vai conseguir ver a paginação porque depende de outras ferramentas aqui do sistema entende?

Comment: ctrl+U e copie o código fonte

Answer (score 1):

Faça assim :

//div que tem o panel.

```
<div class="span7 center"> box </div>
```

//e use esse .css abaixo para centralizar.

```
.center {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não me lembro bem, mas caso o Bootstrap 2.1.0 não tenha a class `.pagination-centered` basta criá-la. Veja o [exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/XZpf3/):

```css
.pagination-centered {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination pagination-centered">
    <ul id="paginator_pages">
        <li class="disabled" id="paginator_previous"><a href="javascript:void(0)">«</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toogle="tab">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toogle="tab">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" data-toogle="tab">3</a></li><li class="" id="paginator-next"><a href="javascript:void(0)">»</a></li></ul>
</div>
```